# Injecting jQuery snippets through GTM Custom HTML tags with RequireJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs, google-tag-manager, mixpanel

#### Background:

We have several projects, where the analytics team are wiring up `mixpanel.track()` calls to clicks on elements by adding `JS` (or, rather `jQuery`) snippets in GTM Custom HTML tags. For instance:

```
$(".btn.business").click(function() {
    mixpanel.track("Segmentation - Business");
});
```

Probably not the most obvious way to go, but that allows them to manage tracking independently, without need for changes in app's JS or markup.

#### Problem:

On a new project, we wanted to go with RequireJS for module loading, and it works just fine except that the analytics' snippets tend to get executed before jQuery is even loaded, which, of course, results in errors like

> ReferenceError: $ is not defined

#### Question:

If we decide to keep to the whole inject-JS-through-gtm approach, how can the snippets be re-written so they 'wait' for jQuery to load? Or, are there any other 'global' points of interference in GTM which would fix the issue? I do not think analytics would go for vanilla JS.

#### Additional info:

The overall page layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript">
      //NewRelic script - just to be honest
    </script>
    <title><!-- TITLE --></title>
    <!-- A bunch of links: favicon, css, fonts -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
      //MixPanel script, generic
    </script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- 
      All page markup 
      goes
      here
    -->
    <script src="/member/res/common/scripts/libs/require.min.js?v=601722621"></script>
    <script src="/member/content/js/config.js?v=601722621"></script>
    <script>
      require.config({
        urlArgs: 'v=601722621'
      });
    </script>

    <script>
      require(['Shared/Header', 'Report/report', 'Shared/sharingModal']);
    </script>
    <script>
      var dataLayer = [
        //the default dataLayer fillings
      ];
    </script>

    <noscript>
      <!-- GTM iframe -->
    </noscript>
    <script>
      //GTM script, generic
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The (partial) config.js:

```
require.config({

  baseUrl: '/member/Content/js/',
  // wait befor give up load js module (by default 7s)
  waitSeconds: 30,

  paths: {
    // jQuery and validation, other vendors
    jquery: ['https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min', './../../res/Common/Scripts/libs/jquery-2.1.4.min'],
    jqueryValidate: ['https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.14.0/jquery.validate.min', './../../res/Common/Scripts/libs/jquery.validate.min'],

    //etc...

    clipboard: './../../res/TM/Scripts/modules/clipboard.min', // copy text to clipboard
  }
});

// Load global js
require(['app', 'jquery', 'spinner'], function(app) {
  app.init();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to leave your code written as-is for the most part, and instead lean on the Trigger Type.

Configure a trigger for your tag(s) which uses one of the non-default Trigger Types:

- Page View (default)
- DOM Ready (may work for your needs)
- Window Loaded (last event possible in default GTM - everything is loaded at this point in most scenarios).

[image]